# Pattern matching type mismatch error

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, covariance, type-inference, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to construct a type `IO`, `IO[File, String]` would represent something like a File operation that will return String as result.
And I have the following problem:

```
object testcase1 {
  import scala.language.higherKinds

  trait IO[-F[+_], +A]
  case class Return[-F[+_], +A](value: A) extends IO[F, A]

  def fn[F[+_], A](op: IO[F, A]): A = op match {
    case Return(v) => v    // <---- type mismatch error
  }
}

type mismatch
found   : v.type (with underlying type Any)
required: A
   case Return(v) => v
                     ^
```

I expected `v` to be of type `A`, did I miss something here?
I suspect it is something related to those `+` and `-`, but I can't see the problem...

---

More detail:
the reason I suspect the problem is hidden in type variance is because the code compiles fine **if either** `+A` becomes `A` or `-F` becomes `F` in `trait IO`, like:

```
object testcase1 {
  import scala.language.higherKinds

  trait IO[F[+_], +A]    // note the missing "-" in front of F
  case class Return[F[+_], +A](value: A) extends IO[F, A]

  def fn[F[+_], A](op: IO[F, A]): A = op match {
    case Return(v) => v    // <---- compiles FINE!!
  }
}
```

as @igx has suggested, using `v.asInstanceOf[A]` can force it compile, but as I'm only presenting a much minimized problem here, I'll have to add `asInstanceOf` in quite a lot of places to make it works.

Plus, I'd really like to know the reason behind this error~~

Answer (score 0):

he type A at Return is not guaranteed that is the same as the A in fn . if you are sure than you can force it (but I am not sure that this what you want to do ) :

```
object testcase1 {
  import scala.language.higherKinds

  trait IO[-F[+_], +A]
  case class Return[-F[+_], +A](value: A) extends IO[F, A]

  def fn[F[+_], A](op: IO[F, A]): A = op match {
    case Return(v) => v.asInstanceOf[A]    // <---- OK
  }
}
```

Comment: Or use: `case Return(v : A) => v`

Comment: @igx sorry, I still can't see why "the type A at Return is not guaranteed that is the same as the A in fn", could you please explain more or give an example~? thanks~~

Comment: @Chris i.e change to def fn[F[+_],X](op: IO[F, A]):A= op match ... and it will work , so X and A are different or you can remove it (since it is not in use) like this : def fn[F[+_]](op: IO[F, A]):A= op match . I  hope that's clarify and answer your question

Comment: @igx the `A` cannot be removed from `fn`, because then `A` will be undefined.

Comment: @Chris , my point is that they are not the same. what do you mean undefined? at least it compiles . you can also use the first option I suggested

Comment: @igx hm... no, the second option doesn't compile.

Comment: @igx and about your point, say a call like: `fn(Return[F, Int](1))`, the `A` of `Return` is `Int`, just as is the `A` in `fn`, I don't see the problem here...

Comment: @Chris I don't what to say, both options compiled on my machine.

Comment: @igx what version of scala you're using? the 2.10.2 on ideone can't compile your option2, see: http://ideone.com/Bfmd9N

Comment: @Chris Sorry about that , strangely I successfully compiled it on a maven project that I had open on my IDE, when I tried to do the same on other project (simple worksheet) I got an error as you described . I will remove it

Comment: @Chris anyway I think the 1st option is what you are looking for and solves it

Comment: @Chris was the answer helpful ?